# In Dart, how can I save a string to a user's local file, without using dart.io?

Tags: dart

I have a Dart [client side only, polymer] web-app. So I cannot use dart.io. I would like to do this semi-pseudo (language/platform mix!) code:

```
  ..
  String str = "a load of text";
  File file = new File('C:\\folder\\test.txt');
  file.write(str);
  file.close();
```

or

```
  window.clipboard.copy(str);
```

so the user can paste it.  I have used a **TextAreaElement** to put the string on (using **textarea.value=str**), and then the user can copy and paste it himself, but that's a bit naff.
Thanks
Steve

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897619/using-html5-javascript-to-generate-and-save-a-file/32295448

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, you cannot write to files on the file system from a web app. The restriction is from browsers and their security model.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that was the case, but stackedit and other web apps export to local disk. I see httprequest (haven't used it). It looks like I need to use that, but I'd prefer an automatic copy to the clipboard. Still learning....!<br>Cheers, S